# argument of type "u16_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "u16_t [2]*" - uIP library

Tags: c, windows, tcp, ip, micro-ip

I am trying to initiate a TCP/IP connection using the standard library uIP. This code was taken directly from the manual, which shows how to open a new connection to a specific IP address (in this case my Windows localhost machine).

```
u16_t ipaddr[2];
uip_ipaddr(ipaddr, 127,0,0,1);
uip_connect(ipaddr, HTONS(51719));
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
argument of type "u16_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "u16_t [2]*"
```

shown for the last line (the `uip_connect()` function). What am I doing wrong? This is literally a cut-and-paste from the uIP reference manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `uip_connect()` requires an `uip_ipaddr_t*` type as its first argument.

`uip_ipaddr_t` is typedefed from `uint16_t[2]`. You have to pass the address of your array to get `uip_ipaddr_t*`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I'm just confused as to why they wrote it that way in the manual as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that one is a 2D array `u16_t [2]*` while the other is a one dimensional array `u16_t *`.  They are obviously not compatible.

Comment: But that's exactly how they have it coded in the manual. Even when I define it as `u16_t ipaddr`, I still get the same error.